# Few questions on finding ONE sided limits.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I need some help, some questions to check my answers, and other questions that I was not very sure about. They are based on limits.

3: using $lim_{x\to 0} \left(\frac{sinx}{x} \right)=1$ find limits of 
$lim_{x\to 0} \left( \frac{\sin(k\cdot x)}{x} \right)$, where $k$ is a constant

For this one I was not really sure, sin 0 = 0 but not really sure how to start the problem off.

Thank you for all  the help!

EDIT: just need help with 3 now.

Answer (score 1):

can you re-type your question in latex? for example, 2a, you mean
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{2x}(x-1)}{{\left|x-1\right|}}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\frac{\sqrt{2}x(x-1)}{{\left|x-1\right|}}
\end{equation}
I guess you mean the first one? IF so, $x\to 1^-$ we have the limit is $-\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: first one yes, sorry i didnt do it clear.

Comment: just need 3 now, 1 and 2 are all set.

Answer (score 1):

For 3:
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin kx}{x} \right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin kx}{x} \cdot \frac{k}{k }\right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin kx}{kx} \cdot k\right) = \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac{\sin kx}{kx}\right) \cdot k $$
Did you get it?

Comment: Did i understand your question correctly? It is very poorly formatted.

Comment: I think the above comment is correct.